# Highcharts force xAxis datetime range

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highcharts with datetime type xAxis and irregular timestamped data.
Is there any possibility to enforce range on the axis? Currently, even if I set min and max, based on data bounds, Highchart tends to determine x axis range based on some internal algorithm, showing i.e. more than 6 weeks, even if data is limited to one month only. This effects in "blank margins".

Comment: Sure, set [minRange](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.minRange) option. If this won't help, check `xAxis.startOnTick` and `xAxis.endOnTick` properties - you may want them set to false.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the point - I need something like _maxRange_, but there is no such option...

Comment: See [user voice ticket](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/4120781-maxrange-for-axes) for `maxRange`.

Comment: If you post a fiddle, you may get a solution. Did you try the start/end on tick properties combined with a min and max? Also possibly ceiling and floor properties?

Comment: Yes, I have tried min/max and startOnTick/endOnTick combinations. No results as for now. Please, find [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/grzegorz_ewald/xmn4jm9z/3/) attached.